# How to add More than 15 rows in Gridster (dsmorse gridster.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, gridster

I have built a Form Designing application on top of

> dsmorse(dsmorse.github.io/gridster.js/)

grister and I can't add widget in more than 15 rows. I tried `gridster.options.max_rows=60;` but it didn't worked in my case.

Comment: Try and look at the ´[max_size]´ function

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I think that  defines the size of widget i want to change capacity of grid. Total Number of rows grid can conatain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set max_rows to the number the rows desired

example

```
gridster[{0}] = $('#grTer_{0} ul').gridster({
                widget_base_dimensions: ['auto', 55],
                autogenerate_stylesheet: true,
                min_cols: 1,
                max_cols: 12,
                max_rows: 140,
                extra_rows : 40,
                widget_margins: [30, 30]
            }).data('gridster');
```

by default max_rows is 15 row max